# Simply String syntax in java confusion

Tags: java, string

I have a simply doubt about syntax in Java related with Strings.
Could some one tell me what is the difference between the strings in the following code?

```
String[] firstS = {"word1","word2"};
String secondS[] = {"word1","word2"};
```

I can not realize what is the difference because doing some for loop both String have the same output.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference, but the first is often considered better style.